# How user-friendly is a navbar that extends across the right half of the top strip?

Tags: gui-design, navigation

The usual advice is not to try to be adventurous when placing the nav items: put them where the reader expects them - horizontally across the top or beneath a banner, or vertically down the lefthand side.

But how does putting them across only the right half of the top strip, leaving the left half for other items, compare for usability with using a standard full-width bar? How for example does this

[image]

(nav items in right half of top strip only)

compare for usability with this

[image]

(nav items across full width, at top of top strip)

or this

[image]

(nav items across full width, below top strip)

Comment: Have you tested this with real-world links? It may not be an option to keep them on the right.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I am at an early stage of site design and am using "#" placeholders for the link URLs. But I know what the link texts will be. They will fit fine in the available space. I just don't know whether doing it like this will confuse readers or annoy them or fail to attract their attention.

Comment: @ruffle about your comment, try to use real content as soon as you can, so if you already know the text of those links test with it.

Comment: Thanks - that's good advice. They are "Home", "Authors", "Themes", "About" and "Contact". But is there some general-purpose advice about the usability of this positioning? Maybe generally speaking it's a no-no, only worth considering if there's an excellent reason? Or maybe it's usually as good a place as the alternatives? I'm trying to keep the question general so that answers will be useful to more visitors here than if I just said "can someone please help me with designing my site" :)

Comment: There's no "no no" usability doesn't work that way. Consider how people navigate your site, or will navigate your site, are they in page links or rarely used links that aren't article led. I know it's not the answer you're looking for, but UX isn't black and white.

Answer (score 2):

This is my opinion about the different parts of the page (from your images), in order to help the layout to be understood correctly. There is nothing as actually testing with users to see the effects of any hypothesis.

Background color differentiates blocks of content; in this scenario lines (not border lines) serve as a secondary division inside a block.
If all blocks have the same background color, lines can be used to separate them.

The problem I see with your third approach is that the only block with a different background color is the navigation links. The Header and the Page content have the same background color, and so the same "level". This makes the navigation block look like it is external to the Page (like an admin toolbar).

The second approach uses the background color as a line, which can make the content of that "line" to be ignored.

My advice would be to either:

- use a background color for the header and another one for the navigation block (but careful)
- use a background color for the whole header block
- don't use background colors and use lines to separate blocks. In this case the navigation block might or not have its own separation

About the position of the navigation block, my impression is that the closer it is to the top edge, rather than the rest of the content in the page, the more "external" it looks.

This is a proposal if it helps.

[image]